# Excel find and pivot

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a large excel 2016 file (26k rows) . I have 7 terms that I need to search for and extract the rows that these items are in, into another excel file or workbook or delete everything in the file except the rows that I need. Then I need to create a pivot table with all the rows that have certain terms e.g. locked, open, sold etc

For example:

Search excel for the following items and move the corresponding row to a new workbook or delete everything else.

_rb_carsales_200
_rb_carparts_201
_rb_main

Create pivot table for the above items that have locked, open, sold in the status column.

Comment: I'm not 100% on what you are asking, but couldn't you create a pivot - then use the filter to only target the terms (or, conversely, to *take out the terms*). Then have a status column with the information you are looking for, for the terms?

Comment: You can use Advanced Filter to copy the corresponding rows to a new sheet then Create the pivot table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a filter?

Helper column
If(And(CriteriaColumn1 = Criteria1,OR(CriteriaColumn2=Criteria2, CriteriaColumn2=Criteria3,....),"X","")

Then Filter for X. Copy the table and paste into your new location

Comment: Several ways: 1) Select your data, go to the "Data" tab on the ribbon, and click on "Filter". 2) Select your data, go to the "Insert" tab on the ribbon, and insert a table. 3) Select a cell in your data, and hit Alt+A+T

Comment: Thanks do you know how to create a pivot table then of the info i need.

Comment: I'd google that